# How to Use gzip to compress messages in web services before send?

Tags: java, xml, web-services, gzip, wss4j

I know Java prog. langugage but, I am a complete beginner in Java EE and web services, soap etc. I need to compress a message before sending and add a signature to it with Apache wss4j. 
I followed tutorials in Netbeans website and created a web service and a web service client which consumes the corresponding service.(A number adding service and a client) I am reading the official Java EE documents but i couldn't understand and write something. I am searching for example codes and projects but coulndn't find related codes or understand which I found.

These are the ones I found:

- http://www.devx.com/Java/Article/28816/1954
- http://ws.apache.org/wss4j/xref-test/org/apache/ws/security/message/SignatureTest.html

But where to add these codes in my project. How to add signature and compress? Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GZip present in java.util.zip pkg.

```
java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream;
java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream;
```

to zip and unzip you need to use `org.apache.axis.encoding.Base64` to encode and decode.